# What code should i write to get JSR bytecode in my .class?

Tags: java, javac, bytecode, low-level

I need to get JSR (of course with corresponding RET) bytecodes in destination .class file. But i can't imagine what Java code should i write to get it?

P.S. i work with Java 1.6

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150154/what-java-compilers-use-the-jsr-instruction-and-what-for?

Comment: Now i've seen, thanks