# Why does the Java Compiler copy finally blocks?

Tags: java, jvm, javac, try-catch-finally, try-finally

When compiling the following code with a simple `try/finally` block, the Java Compiler produces the output below (viewed in the ASM Bytecode Viewer):

***Code:***

```
try
{
    System.out.println("Attempting to divide by zero...");
    System.out.println(1 / 0);
}
finally
{
    System.out.println("Finally...");
}
```

***Bytecode:***

```
TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L1 
L0
 LINENUMBER 10 L0
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 LDC "Attempting to divide by zero..."
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
L2
 LINENUMBER 11 L2
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 ICONST_1
 ICONST_0
 IDIV
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
L3
 LINENUMBER 12 L3
 GOTO L4
L1
 LINENUMBER 14 L1
FRAME SAME1 java/lang/Throwable
 ASTORE 1
L5
 LINENUMBER 15 L5
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 LDC "Finally..."
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
L6
 LINENUMBER 16 L6
 ALOAD 1
 ATHROW
L4
 LINENUMBER 15 L4
FRAME SAME
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 LDC "Finally..."
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
L7
 LINENUMBER 17 L7
 RETURN
L8
 LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L8 0
 MAXSTACK = 3
 MAXLOCALS = 2
```

When adding a `catch` block in between, I noticed that the Compiler copied the `finally` block **3** times (not posting the bytecode again). This seems like a waste of space in the class file. The copying also doesn't seem to be limited to a maximum number of instructions (similar to how inlining works), since it even duplicated the `finally` block when I added more calls to `System.out.println`.

---

However, the result of a custom compiler of mine that uses a different approach of compiling the same code works exactly the same when executed, but requires less space by using the `GOTO` instruction:

```
public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
 // parameter  args
 TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L1 
L0
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 LDC "Attempting to divide by zero..."
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 ICONST_1
 ICONST_0
 IDIV
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
 GOTO L2
L1
FRAME SAME1 java/lang/Throwable
 POP
L2
FRAME SAME
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 LDC "Finally..."
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
L3
 RETURN
 LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L3 0
 MAXSTACK = 3
 MAXLOCALS = 1
```

Why does the Java Compiler (or the Eclipse Compiler) copy the bytecode of the `finally` block multiple times, even using `athrow` to rethrow exceptions, when the same semantics can be achieved using `goto`? Is this part of the optimization process, or is my compiler doing it wrong?

---

(The output in both cases is...)

```
Attempting to divide by zero...
Finally...
```

Comment: Is said custom compiler using it's own pseudo-instructions?

Comment: It compiles to Java Bytecode using the ASM framework...

Comment: Neither of the "answers" so far answer the basic question: **Why** does it duplicate these blocks?

Comment: `javac` used to use `jsr` (jump subroutine) to only write `finally` code once, but there were some problems related to the new verification using stack map tables.  I assume they went back to cloning the code just because it was the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @jeffrey-bosboom looks like it's not a recent change, i'm finding discussions about this starting from 2006.

Comment: @uraimo Sounds about right -- verification by stack maps was introduced in Java 6, which came out late 2006, and of course the problem would have been discussed before that.

Comment: Are there any cases where my approach would work differently from the `javac` one? For example, if I had a `try { return 1; } finally { return 2; }`, would `javac` inline the finally block before the `return` statement? (Because I suspect that my bytecode would return `1` in this case)

Comment: seems bytecode output of `custom compiler` is incorrect as it `pop` the `throwable` object out in `L1` part. so your function will never throw `exception` out while it's possible to throw a `runtime exception`

Comment: Expanding what @D3Hunter said, the two bytecode versions are not equivalent! In the first, the `ArithmeticException` is rethrown after `println("Finally...")` is executed but in the second, the exception is discarded and the method returns normally. Hence, you should have also seen a difference in the output when executing these two samples. The first one would additionally print the exception and terminate with an non-zero exit status (unless a calling method catches and ignores the exception, or you set a custom uncaught exception handler).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Inlining Finally Blocks

The question your asking has been analyzed in part at [http://devblog.guidewire.com/2009/10/22/compiling-trycatchfinally-on-the-jvm/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407142041/http://devblog.guidewire.com/2009/10/22/compiling-trycatchfinally-on-the-jvm/) (wayback machine web archive link)

The post will show an interesting example as well as information such as (quote):

> finally blocks are implemented by inlining the finally code at all possible exits from the try or associated catch blocks, wrapping the whole thing in essentially a “catch(Throwable)” block that rethrows the exception when it finishes, and then adjusting the exception table such that the catch clauses skip over the inlined finally statements.  Huh?  (Small caveat:  prior to the 1.6 compilers, apparently, finally statements used sub-routines instead of full-on code inlining.  But we’re only concerned with 1.6 at this point, so that’s what this applies to).

---

### The JSR instruction and Inlined Finally

There are differing opinions as to why inlining is used though I have not yet found a definitive one from an official document or source.

There are the following 3 explanations:

**No offer advantages - more trouble:**

Some believe that finally in-lining is used because JSR/RET did not offer major advantages such as the quote from [What Java compilers use the jsr instruction, and what for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150154/what-java-compilers-use-the-jsr-instruction-and-what-for)

> The JSR/RET mechanism was originally used to implement finally blocks. However, they decided that the code size savings weren't worth the extra complexity and it got gradually phased out.

**Problems with verification using stack map tables:**

Another possible explanation has been proposed in the comments by @jeffrey-bosboom, who I quote below:

> javac used to use jsr (jump subroutine) to only write finally code once, but there were some problems related to the new verification using stack map tables. I assume they went back to cloning the code just because it was the easiest thing to do.

**Having to Maintain Subroutine Dirty Bits:**

An interesting exchange in the comments of question [What Java compilers use the jsr instruction, and what for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150154/what-java-compilers-use-the-jsr-instruction-and-what-for) points that JSR and subroutines "added extra complexity from having to maintain a stack of dirty bits for the local variables".

*Below the exchange:*

> @paj28: Would the jsr have posed such difficulties if it could only
>   call declared "subroutines", each of which could only be entered at
>   the start, would only be callable from one other subroutine, and could
>   only exit via ret or abrupt completion (return or throw)? Duplicating
>   code in finally blocks seems really ugly, especially since
>   finally-related cleanup may often invoke nested try blocks. – 
>   supercat Jan 28 '14 at 23:18
>
> @supercat, Most of that is already true. Subroutines can only be
>   entered from the start, can only return from one place, and can only
>   be called from within a single subroutine. **The complexity comes from
>   the fact that you have to maintain a stack of dirty bits for the local
>   variables and when returning, you have to do a three-way merge.** – 
>   Antimony Jan 28 '14 at 23:40

Comment: Not related to my question, but is it still possible to use the `JSR` and `RET` instructions, for example for *actual* subroutines (duh...)?

Comment: @Clashsoft I don't think you can. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21150629/1688441 , `The JSR instruction is actually not even allowed in Java 7 classfiles. It is only allowed in version 49.0 or earlier classfiles, corresponding to Java 5 or earlier. In practice, it fell out of use long before that.`

Comment: So subroutines would simply be compiled to private methods next to the containing method?

Comment: not sure... after i come back from coffee will take a look

Comment: "Inlining was abandoned". I am confused: isn't inlining exactly what we are getting here? The way I understand the term, when they don't use `JSR` to place the finally block "out of line" then instead the finally blocked gets *inlined* multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Compiling this:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Attempting to divide by zero...");
        System.out.println(1 / 0);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception!");
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("Finally...");
    }

}
```

And looking at result of javap -v, the finally block is simply appended at the end of every section that manages an exception (adding the catch, a finally block at line 37 is added, the one at 49 is for unchecked java.lang.Errors):

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...);
descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_VARARGS
Code:
  stack=3, locals=3, args_size=1
     0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     3: ldc           #3                  // String Attempting to divide by zero...
     5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     8: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    11: iconst_1
    12: iconst_0
    13: idiv
    14: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
    17: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    20: ldc           #6                  // String Finally...
    22: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    25: goto          59
    28: astore_1
    29: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    32: ldc           #8                  // String Exception!
    34: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    37: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    40: ldc           #6                  // String Finally...
    42: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    45: goto          59
    48: astore_2
    49: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    52: ldc           #6                  // String Finally...
    54: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    57: aload_2
    58: athrow
    59: return
  Exception table:
     from    to  target type
         0    17    28   Class java/lang/Exception
         0    17    48   any
        28    37    48   any
```

Looks like that the original finally blocks implementation resembled what you are proposing but since Java 1.4.2 javac started inlining finally blocks, from "[An Evaluation of Current Java Bytecode Decompilers](http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas01sd/decompilers.pdf)"[2009] of Hamilton & Danicic:

> Many of the old decompilers expect the use of
>   subroutines for try-finally blocks but javac 1.4.2+ generates
>   inline code instead.

A [blog post](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/finally-finally-block/) from 2006 that discusses this:

> The code in lines 5-12 is identical to the code in lines 19-26, which actually translates to the count++ line. The finally block is clearly copied.

Comment: Why do you repeat code already available from the question creator?

Comment: It's the same code with an added catch, i put it here to be sure that it was what he meant and to show the source i compiled. If you are referring to the javap dump, it's needed and actually more clear and easy to read than what he posted.