# What does `at ReturnAddress` mean in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

I'm reading [JVMS, §2 The Structure of The Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html).

[2.3.3. The returnAddress Type and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.3)

I have some questions here. What is the `returnAddress`?

Is returnAddress the address of the previous frame?

Can anyone explain that briefly?

> The returnAddress type is used by the Java Virtual Machine's jsr, ret, and jsr_w instructions (§jsr, §ret, §jsr_w)

I saw that `returnAddress` was instructed `jsr,jsr_w,ret` using (finally statement for Java), starting from JDK7 virtual machine is not allowed to appear these several instructions (jsr.. ), so does it still have a point of existence?

Comment: Why are you linking to section 2.11.8? Is that relevant for your question?

Comment: Section 2.3.3 (that you refer to with its heading) has a description of the `returnAddress` type. What is it that you don't understand about it? "The returnAddress type is used by the Java Virtual Machine's jsr, ret, and jsr_w instructions (§jsr, §ret, §jsr_w). The values of the returnAddress type are pointers to the opcodes of Java Virtual Machine instructions. Unlike the numeric primitive types, the returnAddress type does not correspond to any Java programming language type and cannot be modified by the running program."

Comment: See also: [What Java compilers use the jsr instruction, and what for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150154/what-java-compilers-use-the-jsr-instruction-and-what-for)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  I'm sorry,i changed it now.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I added some information about my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is returnAddress the address of the previous frame?

No, the `returnAddress` is a position in the current bytecode containing the `jsr` or `jsr_w` and `ret` instructions.

As [the documentation of these instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.jsr) describes, it is used to represent the bytecode location right after the `jsr` or `jsr_w` instruction, to allow `ret` to resume at that location.

> I saw that `returnAddress` was instructed `jsr,jsr_w,ret` using (finally statement for Java), starting from JDK7 virtual machine is not allowed to appear these several instructions …, so does he still have a point of existence?

In Java classes with a version of 51 or higher, these instructions may not appear, hence, the code may never deal with values of type `returnAddress`. Related to this, [`StackMapTable` attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.4) have no way to denote the type `returnAddress`.

Still, as long as JVMs are backward compatible to older class files, `returnAddress` is a thing.

Comment: Thank a lots。
You mentioned that if it makes sense for backward compatibility。
then in other words，If our bytecode versions are all 1.7 +, then the `returnADDRESS`  is useless, right?

Comment: Correct, for bytecode targeting Java 7+, there will be no use of the returnaddress type.